# java grid bag layout: avoiding center alignment

Tags: java, alignment, jpanel, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

In my GUI application, I have several JPanels that are instantiated at various points during the running of my program, and certain actions will cause one of them to be displayed in a scroll pane:

```
mViewport.setViewportView(currentPanel);
```

The trouble is, that my panels are done using Grid Bag Layouts, and the behaviour of that is to center itself within the JScrollPane it is inside of. This make the GUI look weird.

Anyone know of a way to force a grid bag layout panel to top-left align?

Thanks!

---

EDIT

Note that here I am asking about the alignment of the entire panel within its scroll pane, not about the components within the panel.

Comment: Maybe you could post some working code for us?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood, that is seriously the only line of code that is relevant to the question. The code for the JPanel is just stock standard netbeans autogenerated code.

Comment: I was thinking more of a working example that I could quickly copy paste and try out myself. There is obviously a lot more that is relevant than that single line of code :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood, thanks for your comments. There was alot of inertia in posting the rest of it cos it is a massive class... Anyway check out my own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question after some fiddling around:

Setting weights appears to be able to affect alignment of the components within the `JPanel` for which the `GridBagLayout` was used. However, it didn't have an effect on the alignment of the `JPanel` within the `JScrollPane`.

I found a rather simple solution, which is to **not** put the `JPanel` directly inside of the `JScrollPane`, as I was doing with my earlier code:

```
if (currentPanel != mCurrentPanel)
{
    mViewport.setViewportView(currentPanel);
}
```

... but instead to put an "outer" `JPanel` inside the `JScrollPane`, and set that to use a `FlowLayout`. Then when I want to switch panels, I remove the old and place the panel within the "outer" panel.

```
if (currentPanel != mCurrentPanel)
{
    if (mCurrentPanel != null)
    {
        mOuterPanel.remove(mCurrentPanel);
    }
    mCurrentPanel = currentPanel;
    mOuterPanel.add(mCurrentPanel);
}
```

This approach worked rather well, because it meant I only had to effect changes in one class, instead of each of the many panels I had.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to set the weights (in the `GridBagConstraints`) on one or more of the components inside your panel. This has the effect of "pushing" the components to take up more of the available space (without weights, the components will only take up what they need, and the panel will be centred within the available space).

If you wanted to align the components at the top left of the scroll pane, set the bottom component's y weight to 1.0, and set the right-most component's x weight to 1.0.

Comment: @Ash, thanks for the answer, unfortunately it did not seem to work in my particular application. I have found an alternative solution and answered my own question.

Comment: To not misshape my contained components I added an empty Label in a new bottom row and a new right column which x and y weight I set to 1. ...thanks for your answer!