# GridBagLayout padding

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am using a `GridBagLayout` to (currently) display two rows. I am aware this layout is overkill for this task, but am trying to learn how to use it. The problem is that I have added the two panels to the two separate rows and there is a huge gap around the content (see image and code below):
[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264533379009864500.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264533379009864500.png)

```
Image background;
    public Table(){
        super();
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("pokerTableV2.png"));
        background = ii.getImage();
        setSize(Constants.FRAME_WIDTH, Constants.TABLE_HEIGHT);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JButton button = new JButton("hello world");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,100));
        panel1.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        add(panel1, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;

        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        middlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,350));
        middlePanel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        middlePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        add(middlePanel, constraints);


    }
```

Comment: You have accepted the wrong answer

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I disagree: When there are two ways of accomplishing the same thing, you cannot contend that one is wrong when both work. Do note that I did acknowledge that it is possible to accomplish this using `GridBagConstraints`, it's just that I prefer the alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, with `GridBagLayout`, if the contents do not fill the entire container that it is in, it will automatically center all its contents within its container. That is why you are getting a really large gap.

There are essentially two ways to fix this:

1. The hard way: Fiddle with the `GridBagConstraints`. I had limited success with this when trying to avoid the centre-ing behaviour.
2. The easy way: Put the `GridBagLayout` inside of a `FlowLayout`, and then set the alignment of the `FlowLayout` to top-left, or whatever you wish.

I have asked, and answered, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099227/java-grid-bag-layout-avoiding-center-alignment) myself sometime last week.

So in your case you are adding your `panel1` and `middlePanel` directly to the JFrame (?), with a `GridBagLayout`

```
JFrame (GridBagLayout)
 - panel1
 - middlePanel
```

I would suggest this alternative structure instead, to get rid of all the extra space (and centre alignment as well, if you like).

```
JFrame (FlowLayout)
 - JPanel (GridBagLayout)
   - panel1
   - middlePanel
```

HTH

Comment: -1 This answer is incorrect. What you need to do is to set the weightx and weighty properties on your GridBagConstraints. The default for both will be 0.0 which causes everything to 'center'

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
constraints.weightx = 1d;
constraints.weighty = 1d;
```

[JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx) for `weightx`/`weighty` says:

> Specifies how to distribute extra horizontal/vertical space.

[JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) for `fill`:

> This field is used when the component's display area is larger 
>   than the component's requested size. It determines whether to 
>   resize the component, and if so, how.

Comment: You also cannot reuse `constraints` like that. You need to create a new instance for the second panel.